# Variable not holding value and dumping contents

Tags: php, apache, debian

Normally I can find what I am looking for on here, even if I have to piece a few things together. This is the first  time I haven't been able to find anything!

Ok so I have an API that I wrote and everything was working fine on my localhost.

When we transferred it to the server, that's when things started going wrong. That is why I have tagged this with Debian and Apache as I feel the issue could lie there somewhere.

The API is working correctly and is returning the JSON string as it should.

The result of the API call gets loaded into a variable (on WAMP on my PC it works fine) and I then make use of the variable later in my code.

On the server the variable gets dumped and then loses its value.

```
<?php 

    include 'api.php';

    $departure = $_GET['departure'];

    $arrival = $_GET['arrival'];

    $routes = call("http://example.com/bus/$departure/$arrival");

    echo '<br><br>'; //These two lines are here only for my debugging
    var_dump($routes); //These are not the issue

?>
```

The var_dump at the end you would think should dump everything a second time but it returns string(0) ""

That is what I mean by it not holding its value

Any ideas?

**SUMMARY:** The bit that gets dumped the the top of the page is exactly what should be returning. The main issue is that the output from the call function gets outputted onto the page **as though** a var_dump is there. The $routes variable isn't storing it hence the actual var_dump returning an empty string

Comment: your call method is returning an empty string.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure the variables are coming through before the call function?

Comment: Please see the summary I have just added

Comment: The issue was with the output buffer in the call function